# get sum of aliases created in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, alias, relevance

I have a bigger SQL query where I use the `Boolean Full-Text Searches` to get the `relevance values`.

I get two relevance values:

- one for **tags (scoreTags)**, multiplied with 3 (higher importance)
- one for **content (scoreContent)**

Both are assigned to `aliasses`. Now I want to add them up for each match in a new alias (superScore) in the same SQL query, but it seems the aliases can't be used by sql to calculate it.

```
(scoreTags + scoreContent) AS superScore
```

I get the follwing error:

```
mysqlt error: [1054: Unknown column 'scoreTags' in 'field list']
```

Here is my complete SQL statement:

```
SELECT csia.cID, csia.ak_tags, p.cParentID, cv.cvName, 
(MATCH (csia.ak_tags) AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 3) AS scoreTags, 
MATCH (psi.content) AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS scoreContent,        
(scoreTags + scoreContent) AS superScore 
FROM CollectionSearchIndexAttributes csia 
LEFT JOIN Pages p 
ON csia.cID = p.cID 
LEFT JOIN CollectionVersions cv 
ON csia.cID = cv.cID 
LEFT JOIN PageSearchIndex psi 
ON csia.cID = psi.cID 
WHERE cv.cvIsApproved = 1 
AND (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
ORDER BY scoreContent DESC, scoreTags DESC, csia.cID DESC
```

I also tried the `SUM` function, but it didn't work either. Do you have any idea how to get this to work? Thank you!

Example of what I want:

Query match with cID 9932 has a relevance value (scoreTags) of 5 and a relevance value of 4 (scoreContent). This superScore should be 19 ((5 * 3) + 4).

Comment: You need to either use subqueries or repeat the expressions in the `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either replace the alias with the actual function, or put this statement into a derived table, and then aggregate from that.

So the first would be:

```
SELECT csia.cID, 
       csia.ak_tags, 
       p.cParentID, cv.cvName, 
       (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) 
        AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' 
        IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 3) AS scoreTags, 
       MATCH (psi.content) 
       AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' 
       IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS scoreContent,        
       (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) 
       AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 3) 
       + 
       MATCH (psi.content) 
       AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS SUperScore        
FROM   CollectionSearchIndexAttributes csia 
LEFT JOIN Pages p 
ON csia.cID = p.cID 
LEFT JOIN CollectionVersions cv 
ON csia.cID = cv.cID 
LEFT JOIN PageSearchIndex psi 
ON csia.cID = psi.cID 
WHERE cv.cvIsApproved = 1 
AND (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
ORDER BY scoreContent DESC, scoreTags DESC, csia.cID DESC
```

Or the second:

```
select cID, 
       ak_tags, 
       cParentID, 
       cvName, 
       scoreTags, 
       scoreContent, 
       scoreTags+ScoreContent as SuperScore from (
            SELECT csia.cID, csia.ak_tags, p.cParentID, cv.cvName, 
            (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) 
            AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' 
            IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 3) AS scoreTags, 
            MATCH (psi.content) 
            AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' 
            IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS scoreContent
      FROM CollectionSearchIndexAttributes csia 
      LEFT JOIN Pages p 
      ON csia.cID = p.cID 
      LEFT JOIN CollectionVersions cv 
      ON csia.cID = cv.cID 
      LEFT JOIN PageSearchIndex psi 
      ON csia.cID = psi.cID 
      WHERE cv.cvIsApproved = 1 
      AND (MATCH (csia.ak_tags) AGAINST ('Bestäubung Bienen Politik' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
 ) x
 ORDER BY scoreContent DESC, scoreTags DESC, csia.cID DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your first solution works, but now the calculation of `scoreTags` is wrong. The second solution doesn't work, I get the following SQL error: `mysqlt error: [1248: Every derived table must have its own alias]`. And I corrected the typos you have, so this can't be the source. I'll try fixing your first solution myself, but if you see anything that might help, don't hesitate to let me know.. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Ok, don't worry. Your first solution works! My calculation seems to be the problem, I get the same mistake with my old query. Thank you!